Как в Aiogram получить айди пользователя из предыдущего сообщения?
@create_user.callback_query(F.data == 'create_profile')
async def create_profile(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Profile.name)
    file = InputMediaPhoto(
        media='AgACAgIAAxkBAAO4ZkCUO8Jt3thlGWxcqCwrfZw6oUgAApnUMRvWJglKXE1X46IJrB4BAAMCAAN4AAM1BA',
        caption='Введите ваше настоящее имя:'
    )
    await call.message.edit_media(
        media=file,
        reply_markup=profile_name_kb(call.message.from_user.first_name)
    )

В клавиатуру нужно передать имя пользователя, но там высвечивается имя бота. Как это сделать?
